# Facebook C# SDK with MVC

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I m working on a facebook ap with Facebook C# SDK and MVC 3.

One of the problem I m having is: multiple versions of Facebook SDK API with several inconsistent versions. Almost every version there is a change in the API and something that works in one version doesnt work in another. There are also major changes between API versions.

I m using the latest version. (6.0.12). I cant find any documentation on how to use the API.

API website has lot of *TODO* pages. (http://csharpsdk.org/) and documentation is not concise.

Should I use another SDK ? What do you recommend? or are there any samples I can use for this version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm much in the same boat as you.
I've followed the blog posts from the members of the Facebook c# SDK team, and their reasoning behind doing the latest major re-work of the API. I'm optimistic and think it's a healthy decision, leveraging the majority of the work from the server to the client instead.

In the end, I think it will benefit our applications with a much more scalable and performant solution than before with the earlier SDK. A good thing if your application gets viral. 
The earlier versions had good and plenty samples and documentation, I only hope that in time the team will be able to provide that with the newer version as well.

For me, I currently have a v5.0x solution in prod, and I'm very eager to jump on the newer SDK, but I'm holding on for good samples as well, hoping for some magic during the upcoming months. 
It's really a question on how long you can wait, I think it's the best SDK out there at this point.

Comment: which version do u recommend or  you have used, that came with samples i can look?

Comment: Thanks. When i look at v5.X i see different dlls such as Facebook.Web, Facebook.Web.Mvc and Facebook. do they all have to be same version? can i mix them?

Comment: I don't know, my guess is that you can't mix. If you haven't already, please rad through Prabir's blog posts. http://blog.prabir.me/

Comment: Thanks. I got it running with 5.x version too. It sucks that they are building a API like this. They need to read more of Joshua Bloch i guess.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having problems with FB breaking old versions like I did, here is a small and brief tutorial I created

http://theocdcoder.com/tutorial-integrating-facebook-authentication-asp-net-mvc-3/